# notification e-mail and invitation letter

Tags: peer-review, conference, paper-submission, international

I submitted a manuscript to an international conference. Later I'm told to download the invitation letter and attend the conference. The question is I have not recieved a formal e-mail notification, presumably titled Acceptance or Rejection Notification, of the paper. So what do you think of this? Are there any international conference that notifies authors by the provision of only a downloadable invitation letter but with no formal e-mail notification?
Thanks!

Comment: _So what do you think of this?_ Check your spam folder, then contact the organisers. _Are there any international conference that notifies authors by the provision of only a downloadable invitation letter but with no formal e-mail notification?_ Predatory conferences probably do (you should avoid those!)

Comment: The conference website is https://waset.org/conference/2019/02/rome/ICWAIM. So please help judge its validity and level, thanks!

Comment: @user2768 nothing in the spam folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to presume, but a quick look through the conference website makes me suspect that it may not be the top of the line for its field. Take a look at the program committee, are they reputable people that you know? If you're a student, can your advisor comment on the conference's value? Can some expert comment on the conference's quality?

Did you receive any reviews?

Were you asked to pay a lot of money to attend?

If any of the above hold, this raises some red flags.

If it's indeed a disreputable venue, I would avoid publishing there. Retract the submission and thank them. There are some places where you wouldn't want your work published.

Again, I'm really not from the field, but not getting reviews, the general look and feel of the conference website (conferences that go out of their way to tell you that they're indexed by all of these libraries is not a good sign) etc. would make me think twice.

As my own advisor wisely said: there are some conferences with a negative impact factor...

EDIT:

This conference is sponsored by WASET, which is almost certainly a predatory publisher. Do NOT publish there.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Academy_of_Science,_Engineering_and_Technology). It is also listed on Beall's list - see [here](https://beallslist.weebly.com).

Comment: The registration fee is 350 euro for students and 450 for nonstudents. It says the conference has been held 21 years.

Comment: Not sure, you need to check with someone in the field.

Comment: I'll add my own skepticism to @Spark 's.  Follow the very bottom link to "Similar Conferences about xxx..." at the bottom of the page.  I have no idea why they would have ~40 different conferences running simultaneously.  When I click on a couple of different ones, they have the same papers listed.  It's a two day conference and they are running 40 different concurrent or sub conferences?  Maybe someone in the field will come along and tell us that, no, this is a venerable conference, but I would not bet on it.  I don't know that it's a scam conference, but I am suspicious.

Comment: @Van definitely predatory. Host publisher listed on Beall's list...

Comment: Thanks. I see. Now I find another conference BDAS (http://bdas.polsl.pl/default.asp). Noticeably, 95 percent of the papers published in the previous conference proceedings are from the host country Poland. Can you give some suggestion on its validity and level?  Another question is how to verify that sponsors listed on the website really sponsor it? Thnaks!

Answer (score -1):

It's normal even for some very top/good conferences to just want you to go to the conference and to not hold you hostage with the conf. paper review.  Even if your paper is rejected for the proceedings (very unlikely, they need papers!), you still can do the conference.  Also, some conferences do the reviews on site, using participants.  So it is not unusual to not have a pre-reviewed proceedings paper.

They want you to go.  If you like the trip pay the money and go.

Comment: This is a predatory conference, OP should not attend

Comment: That's very possible.  However, to the original question, it remains that there is nothing wrong with going to a conference that has not pre-reviewed a proceedings paper.  Normal in chemistry and materials for instance.  They accept you based on topic/abstract.